# Jenkins custom message instead of duration in Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to change the duration label to something custom text, like a url or anything you need per stage?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is hardcoded in the pipeline plugin so there is no way at the moment to configure this text.